# if statement with 3 expressions in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to create an if statement with three expressions.  This is what I tried but does not work:

```
if [ $a = $b -a $c -gt $d ] || [ $a = $f ];
```

With the above expression, if `$a = $f` it does not execute the body of the if statement.  Is this possible?  I have tried different combinations and none seem to work.

EDIT:

Here is my full example as requested:

```
a=9.3
c=9.3.0
q=/a/b/c/d ${a}
if [ "${a}" = "9.2" -a ${c:4:4} -ge 4 ] || [ "${a}" = "9.3" ]
then
    q=/a/b/d ${a}
fi
```

This worked before I added the `|| [ "${a}" = "9.3" ]`

Comment: Works fine with `a=1 b=1 f=1 c=2 d=3`

Comment: Seems to work for me as well, can you try posting a complete executable example, including the values of the variables?

Comment: Works great for me too.  What kind of shell are you using straight up POSIX Bourne Shell or bash (Bourne Again Shell) ?  You can try enclosing your expression in parenthesis `([ "${a}" = "9.2" -a ${c:4:4} -ge 4 ] || [ "${a}" = "9.3" ]); then`

Comment: That's not enough, you should give the whole if statement (up to and including `fi`) in case there is something going on there (e.g. wrong syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is fine. The problem is with your assignments.

This:

```
a=9.3
q=/a/b/c/d ${a}
```

will not make assign `/a/b/c/d 9.3` to the variable `q`.

It will try to run a command named `9.3` and giving it a temporary variable `q=/a/b/c/d`.

Running this script results in two errors that say `9.3: command not found`. Please don't ignore errors or unexpected output. They are important for detecting and diagnosing problems.

I don't know exactly what your intentions are, but you might have meant:

```
a=9.3
c=9.3.0
q="/a/b/c/d ${a}"
if [ "${a}" = "9.2" -a ${c:4:4} -ge 4 ] || [ "${a}" = "9.3" ]
then
    q="/a/b/d ${a}"
fi
```

After running this code, you can do `echo "$q"` and it will say `/a/b/d 9.3` like you might have expected, which shows that the then branch was taken.

Comment: +1, but you should also point that (a) using `[[...]]`is preferred over `[...]` in bash in general and that `-a` (and `-o`) in `[...]` are non-standard; use `&&` and `||` in `[[...]]` instead - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals.